# window.crypto.subtle is undefined when connecting to http://localhost:3000 on firefox

Tags: http, firefox, browser, https, window.crypto

I wanted to start working again on a Single Page Application I was building a few months ago.

It integrates with Azure Cloud and uses its libraries to login.

The deployed instance works using https and it behaves correctly on any browser, the local instance I use for development instead only works on google chrome, not on firefox.

While reading the output console I see:

```
BrowserAuthError: pkce_not_created: The PKCE code challenge and verifier could not be generated. Detail:TypeError: window.crypto.subtle is undefined
```

I've checked that the code is the same running on the deployed instance, plus the local version works on google chrome. I get this error while loading the page using http://localhost:3000 only on firefox.

All this makes me assume that a recent update of firefox decided to block window.crypto.subtle if not using HTTPS, even if connecting to localhost. Do you think this is the issue? Do you know how can I roll back to the previous settings that allowed me to test it locally as well?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is at the beginning of a **SubtleCrypto** [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto):

> Secure context: This feature is available only in secure contexts
> (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers.

Thats the reason why `window.crypto.subtle` it's `undefined`.

If you want test it locally, you could generate HTTPS certificates locally or use tool like [NGROK](https://ngrok.com/) to expose your `http` server as `https` using 1 command instead of trying to rollback to some kind of old version of the browser.